# Twilio Video API - Turn a token into a webcam?

Tags: c#, webforms, twilio-api

There's seems to be next to no documentation for Twilio's video API. I'm wanting to turn the token into a video...

I have written this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    // Connection details
    var accountSid = "hehe";
    var apiKeySid = "hehe";
    var apiKeySecret = "hehe";

    var identity = "hehe";

    // Permission for Token
    var grant = new VideoGrant();
    grant.Room = "Matt";
    var grants = new HashSet { grant };


    // Create an Access Token generator
    var token = new Token(accountSid, apiKeySid, apiKeySecret, identity: identity);


    Response.Write(token.ToJwt());
}
```

Which returns a token, but I don't see how I can then use this token to display a media player. I still use ASP.NET webforms which seems to be a bit of a curse because that's absolutely nothing to even give the slightest on hints as to what to do.

New to C# so I'm sorry if I'm being silly.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but cannot understand the question , can you please elaborate...

Comment: I'm trying to use Twilio's video API. This code returns the access token, but after this point, there's no clue as what to do next?

Comment: Did you checked here https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource